com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Character` from Object value
I'n new in Java and I'm having this error deserializing a JSON to a Java record.
This is my record:
imports...

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public record Character(
        @JsonAlias("fullName") String name,
        @JsonAlias("hogwartsHouse") String house,
        @JsonAlias("birthdate") String birthdate,
        @JsonAlias("index") Integer characterID) {
}


This is the JSON I'm receiving from the API:
{
    "fullName":"Harry James Potter",
    "nickname":"Harry",
    "hogwartsHouse":"Gryffindor",
    "interpretedBy":"Daniel Radcliffe",
    "children":["James Sirius Potter","Albus Severus Potter","Lily Luna Potter"],
    "image":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fedeperin/potterapi/main/public/images/characters/harry_potter.png",
    "birthdate":"Jul 31, 1980",
    "index":0
}

And this is the method where I'm trying to deserialize:
public class Principal {
    private final String URI = "https://potterapi-fedeperin.vercel.app/es/characters?index=0";
    private APIConsumption apiConsumption = new APIConsumption();
    private ConvertData converter = new ConvertData();
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    public void showMain(){
        var json = apiConsumption.consumeAPI(URI);
        System.out.println(json);
        // Character harry = null;
        try {
            Character harry = mapper.readValue(json.toString(), Character.class);
            System.out.println(harry.toString());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

And this is the complete exception I'm getting:
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Character` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 1]
    at dev.alexcastellanos.potterapi.main.Principal.showMain(Principal.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at dev.alexcastellanos.potterapi.PotterApiApplication.run(PotterApiApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at dev.alexcastellanos.potterapi.PotterApiApplication.main(PotterApiApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Character` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1767) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1541) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1446) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(DeserializationContext.java:958) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$CharacterDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:479) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$CharacterDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:425) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4905) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3848) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3816) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at dev.alexcastellanos.potterapi.main.Principal.showMain(Principal.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted

First I was using generic types but I changed it to use Character class directly but it didn't solve the error.

I think you are using the wrong import of Character class in your Principal class.
In java, there is a java.lang.Character class, and you have created a class that has the same name.
In your Principal class, you should import your.package.name.Character instead of java.lang.Character because in Java classes are defined by their Name + package name.

That's correct, Character class (my class) wasn't imported. The IDE recognized Java Character class and I didn't notice. Now I changed the class name and its working.
Thank you!
